# Download files (csv, excel) from azure blob storage using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download the files (csv, excel) from blob storage in Python using the below code.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(CONTAINER_NAME)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client('test12345.csv')

with open("test12345.csv", "wb") as f:
    data = blob_client.download_blob()
    data.readinto(f)'''
```

I am able to download the files, but the downloaded files are stored in byte data. Could anyone please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I am wrong, the implementation is slightly wrong in the last line of your snippet. You could use the below code :

```
f.write(data.readall())
```

Comment: Even tried that and result is same. The download file is not in readable format, it is storing in byte format

Comment: when you download from the portal - are you able to download the file in the readable format?

Comment: yes, if I download it manually, it is in readable format. When trying with Python code, it is storing in byte format.